# Shrink Image to Logo on Menu Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to the Web Coding. Please excuse me if i ask something stupid :/
I have a menu bar on the top.
And bellow is a Div with a image.
I wanted to make the image shrink to a logo on the menu bar when i scroll. What is the "skill" call ? most of the search only show me shrink menu bar but i wanted to shrink a image to logo.
I have tried Google for many term but i still  can't find the term for this 'skill' , please help me out.

```
<div id="menubar">Main Bar Here</div>
<div id="topcontent">
<img src="img.jpg" /> <----this image will shrink up to the menu bar when i scroll down.
</div>
```

Example like this logo http://thebiggroup.co/planb/ that will spin up but i wan additional to stick it to the menu bar.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the actual code of what you've done? Something we can work with? I see your english is not prefect, so it makes it kinda hard to understand what you need.

Comment: @LOTUSMS for the Jquery or JS part i don't have any idea now. I'm trying to look for the term for this technique. i understsand i need to use $().scroll() function on jquery. TQ

Comment: You should post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you saying you want the image to minimize from a full image to an icon size when you shrink the window?

Comment: @LOTUSMS Nope not shrinking the window , just by scrolling down. Like the logo return back to the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, live example **[here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/8zg0vecf)**

```
<head>
  <script>
  function functionScroll(){
    var div = document.getElementById('topDiv');
    div.style.width="50px";
    div.style.height="50px";
  };
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="topDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
<div style="height:100px;width:700px;border:1px solid black;overflow-x:hidden" onscroll="functionScroll()">
  <p>asasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>asasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>asasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>asasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>asasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

</div>
</body>
```

key is to call a function `onscroll` of a `div` and change dimensions of your `div` in that functions. in Your case you can replace `div` with your `img`, or you can set your `img` as a background of the `div`.

Comment: Sorry , i don't get what is this related to the image ? TQ